# Check if mentioned user has certain permission discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to check if a mentioned user in a command (`!checkadmin @User`) has the Administrator permission. How could I do it? I can't find a way to. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is even more easier way. using [Member.guild_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions)
Here you can find the [list of all permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)

```py
@bot.command()
async def admin(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
   if user.guild_permissions.administrator and user != None:
            ctx.send(f'{user.mention} is an admin')
```

Answer (score 1):

just take a quick look at the documentation at:

- [Message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20mentions#discord.Message.mentions)
- [Member.guild_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions)
- and [Permissions.administrator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.administrator)

If you still don't understand it, here's the solution:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.mentions) == 0 or not message.content.startswith("!checkadmin"): return
    mentioned_user = message.mentions[0]
    permissions = mentioned_user.guild_permissions
    is_admin = permissions.administrator

    await message.channel.send("This user is an administrator!" if is_admin else "This user is not an administrator!")
```

Hope I could help

Greets

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a very simple way to do this!

```py
@bot.command()
async def checkadmin(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.message.author
    if member.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).administrator:
        # Do what you want here
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way to do this:

```
@client.command()
async def check_admin(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is not None: await ctx.send("This member is admin" if member.guild_permissions.administrator else "This member is not admin.")
```